# Execute code after some time in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a code which deletes an api column when executed. Now I want it to execute after some time lets say two weeks. Any idea or directions how do I implement it?

My code:

```
      authtoken = models.UserApiToken.objects.get(api_token=token)
      authtoken.delete()
```

This is inside a function and executed when a request is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to get this done:

1. Make it a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/), and trigger it through crontab.
2. Use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), make it a celery task, and use celerybeat to trigger the job after 2 weeks.

I would recommend celery, as it provides a better control of your task queues and jobs.